# How to filter by dates with respect to the timezone they were stored in?

Tags: php, cakephp, filter, timezone, php-chronos

Filtering between 2 months

I need to filter data based on selected month.

We are saving data in `UTC-0` and need to read data in `UTC+1`.

> Situation:

If we save in DB date like `28-02-2017 23:55 (UTC-0)` and make filter for March (03-2017) I should see this input in results (`UTC+1`) and if we have input like `31-03-2017 23:55 (UTC-0)` I should not see this input in results (`UTC+1`).

> Try:

```
$fromDate = new Chronos('2017-03-01 00:00:00', 'Europe/Vienna');
$toDate = new Chronos('2017-04-01 00:00:00', 'Europe/Vienna'); 

$q = $this->Users->find('all')
 ->where(function ($exp, $q) use ($fromDate, $toDate) {
    return $exp->between('Users.created', $fromDate, $toDate);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug the date objects that you've created there, they will hold the exact date that you've passed, and the info to what timezone they refer, consequently when being passed into the query, you will compare to these exact dates - the database (layer) does not care about timezones, it has no clue about them at all.

You need to convert the dates to the timezone that the dates were originally stored in, ie to UTC:

```
$fromDate = new Chronos('2017-03-01 00:00:00', 'Europe/Vienna');
$fromDate = $fromDate->setTimezone('UTC');

$toDate = new Chronos('2017-04-01 00:00:00', 'Europe/Vienna');
$toDate = $toDate->setTimezone('UTC');
```

The dates should now look like:

```
object(Cake\Chronos\Chronos) {
    'time' => '2017-02-28 23:00:00.000000',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'hasFixedNow' => false
}

object(Cake\Chronos\Chronos) {
    'time' => '2017-03-31 22:00:00.000000',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'hasFixedNow' => false
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was taught that 'Europe/Vienna' will automatically convert given DateTime to -1.